# What is low latency kernel? When do we need to use it?

Tags: kernel

What is low latency kernel? 
When do we need to use it?
Any something may be affected when we use low latency kernel?

Comment: What's the difference of function or feature between the low-latency and the generic to cause latency degree?

Answer (score -1):

> lowlatency kernel - very similar to the -preempt kernel and based on the -generic kernel source tree, but uses a more aggressive configuration to further reduce latency. Also known as a [soft real-time kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing#Criteria_for_real-time_computing).

Comment: What's the difference of function or feature between the low-latency and the generic to cause latency degree?